# Insert items into mongo array via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a mongo collection like the code below:

```
const ExerciseSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  exercise: [
    {
      exerciseId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: Exercise,
      },
      period: { type: String, enum: ["day", "night"], required: true },
    },
  ],
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
});
```

When I try to insert multiple exercises at the same time, considering that my exercises are an array, the mongo saves just the first register. For instance, I try to insert:

```
{
    "name": "Exercise 1",
    "exercise": [
        {
            "exerciseId": "1",
            "period": "night"
        },
        {
            "exerciseId": "1",
            "period": "day"
        }
    ]
}
```

And, after saving it, the get method returns me:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "2021-11-30T14:18:42.455Z",
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "Exercise 1",
        "exercise": [
            {
                "exerciseId": "1",
                "period": "night",
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

That is, the mongoose saves just the first register in my array. **Does anyone know why it is happening?**
Hear it my create method from the controller:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const {
    name,
    exercise: [{ exerciseId, period }],
  } = req.body;
  const newExercise = new Exercise({
    name,
    exercise: [{ exerciseId, period }],
  });
  newExercise.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }
    res
      .status(200)
      .send({
        message: "Success",
      });
  });
};
```

Obs: I'm referring to my ExerciseSchema from the controller by "new Exercise(...)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it to update arrays:

```
parent ---> a mongooose doc
parent.child.push({new child object});
parent.markModified('child');
parent.save();
```

in your case child is exercise array and in parent.markModified('child'); you have to put parent.markModified('exercise');

Comment: I'm trying to do with:
```
newExercise.exercise.push(req.body.exercise)
newExercise.markModified('exercise')
```
but it didn't work yet...

Comment: can you attach a console.log of the newExercise const before save?

Comment: follow the console:
```
{
  timestamp: 2021-11-30T16:54:26.622Z,     
  _id: 1,
  name: 'Exercise 1',    
  exercise: [
    {
      exerciseId: 1,
      period: 'night'
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

Comment: My req.body.exercise:

```
[
  {
    exerciseId: '1',
    period: 'night'
  },
  {
    exerciseId: '2',
    period: 'day'
  }
]
```

Comment: and your const exercise take from the body?, if all ok try pushing like this: req.body.exercise.map(exercise => { newExercise.exrcise.pus(exercise)}. pushing every element of the body

Comment: it worked!!! thanks so much by help me!

Comment: np happy that worked